# need ideas for my world, dream related

Tags: science-fiction, urban-fantasy, dream

I'm writing a story where tech has been developed so that people sell their dreams to the Corporation, which uses the information in the dreams for computing power and AI. No one dreams anymore, besides for a few 'dreamouts' (dream holdouts), who are persecuted.

I'm looking for more ideas to flesh out the world. I think there will be an element of 'dreamwalking' where people can visit other people's dreams. And there are aliens involved too. But I would like some more ideas as well.

Basically I am looking for other technologies that would be related to dreaming, or even a fantasy element that is related to dreaming, that would make this world unique and different from the real world. Any and all suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Hello @Xavier Florentine this site is less for brain storming and more for particular questions and such. So i suggest you to narrow down your question and clarify what you actually want. Because reading your question i don't really know what you want. So please just edit your question before others come here to down vote you or something. I really don't want you to get a bad first impression so this is just a friendly advice. If you have edited your question i will try to provide you with an answer so keep in mind that i have your question on my radar. 

Comment: @Xenophile i would also pay if they could give me something to instantly fall asleep. So i can avoid a those sleepless nights i think about useless stuff. Also there would be no more nightmares so that is a plus.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Xavier Florentine you should best describe clearly what you want. As i said this forum is not really suitable for brainstorming. Just narrow it down to one particular problem as i can't really answer your question in such a broad sense. And as i do not know how dreams function in your world in can hardly provide an answer.